# How change a css property?

Tags: javascript, css, plugins, ckeditor

I need to change property in my css file.

In my css file I have :

```
    :root {
  --show: none; 
}

.SLT2_Num_XXX1_Partie::before{
    content: "SLT2_Num_XXX1_Partie";
    display: var(--show);
    border: 1px solid gray;
    font-size: 10px;
    background-color: #fff;
}
```

and this is my plugin :

```
CKEDITOR.plugins.add( 'ShowTagClass', {
icons: 'ShowTagClass,HideDivMetaData',
    init: function( editor ) {

        editor.addCommand( 'ShowTagClass', {
            exec: function( editor ) {

                //code

            }
        });

        editor.ui.addButton( 'ShowTagClass', {
            label: 'supprime la division',
            command: 'ShowTagClass',
            toolbar: 'insert'
        } );

     }
});
```

how can I modify `--show: none` to `--show:block`

I used this but I can not manage it : https://codepen.io/wesbos/pen/adQjoY